# Can we use ArcGIS (sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com) API to get Households for area without any license?

Tags: arcgis-online

In my web site I am using "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer" API for getting households for an area on Google map.

Is this API is free? or did I use this without license?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. According to your question above link is REST link its not the API. You can use REST link to anywhere its for demo purpose. However ESRI API is also free & its works with ESRI REST services only not any REST services (Few Exception)

Answer (score 4):

The sample servers you are referring to.  [Here.](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/9.3/sample-gis-server-and-gis-services)
Should be covered under the data terms and conditions.
Core Esri website use is covered [here](http://www.esri.com/legal/copyright-trademarks) in Esri legal info.
Which is also the link to everything esri legal.
[MLA (E200/E201/E204 and E300)](http://www.esri.com/~/media/Files/Pdfs/legal/pdfs/e200-e300-mla.pdf) states that intellectual property is reserved and use of any type is prohibited without authorization.
Section 4.2 outlines uses not permitted.
Addendum 2 covers use of data. Which according to the [methodology white paper](http://www.esri.com/~/media/files/pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/demographic-update-methodology-2010.pdf) should be considered intellectual data.
This addendum states (I think this covers your question).

> > 1. Demographic, Consumer, and Business Data ("Esri Data"): This Data category > includes the Updated Demographic Database, Census Data,
> >        American Community Survey (ACS) Data, Consumer Spending, Business
> >        Summary, Business Locations, Retail MarketPlace, and Tapestry
> >        Segmentation datasets. Esri Data may be used independently of Software
> >        or Online Services. Each dataset is available under one or more of the
> >        following license types:
>
> - Single Use: Permits access by a single user
>     to access the data for development or internal use on a desktop
>     computer or server. No Internet access is permitted.
> - Internal Site/Server—Known User: Permits access by named (known) users for
>     Licensee's internal use. Web access by those named users is permitted.
> - Public website (noncommercial)—Constituent-Served Model: Permits a
>     municipal government Licensee to use the Data in an externally facing
>     Value-Added Application serving a defined population, provided
>     Licensee does not generate revenue from such use.
> - Public website
>     (commercial) Known User: Permits Licensee to use the Data in an
>     externally facing Value- Added Application for use by named users and
>     to generate revenue from such Value-Added Application.
> - Public
>     website (commercial) Anonymous User: Permits Licensee to use the Data
>     in an externally facing Value-Added Application for general use and to
>     generate revenue from such Value-Added Application.

If you don't interpret any of this as covering your question.

Addendum 3 covers Online Services. Stating that content and developers tools as definitions with other resources should be considered online services, but then the terms refer to the license agreement.  Which doesn't seem to apply in this instance.
[Section 508](http://www.esri.com/legal/section508) seems to lean in the opposite direction, unless of course Esri says it doesn't.
To use any Esri website as a link you must agree to [esri's license](http://www.esri.com/legal/weblink-logoagreement).
Certainly the trademark and copyright are not in question here so as such at the very least their authorization would be in order.
There are links to license request forms (linking) and email contact addresses on many of the pages above for that purpose.

I think of someone inviting me for dinner where they are providing generously at least hamburger, if not steak.
Would I walk around the neighborhood and invite everyone I didn't know to come and put the hurt on them?  Or perhaps just bring the fam and enjoy what is provided with great humility and thankfulness?